# error comparing file content in windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a text file called "isUp.o" containing connection result error, like "FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection timed out".
I just want to check that and change ip variable to a new ip value, but I get the following message in Spanish

```
No se esperaba "FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection timed out" en este momento.
d:\> if [ "FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection timed out" <> "" ] (
```

translation could be:

```
Not waited "FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection timed out" at this moment.
```

I don't know where the problem is.

```
for /f "delims=" %%j in (isUp.o) do (
 set /p result=%%j
 if [ "%result%" <> "" ] (
   set Ip=%alternativeIp%
 )
)
```

Comment: Sadly, insufficient detail for a proper solution. Are you looking for a possibly-empty file, or for a possibly-non-existent file? What content *may* be in the file, and what do you want to do in which circumstances?

Comment: Magoo: file content is "FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection timed out"

Answer (score 0):

This line is not valid batch file syntax

```
 if [ "%result%" <> "" ] (
```

The brackets are a unix shell syntax and don't work in batch.  In addition, there is no `<>` operator in batch.

The line you want is

```
 if not "%result%"=="" (
```

Comment: Not the case. The required line is `if not defined result` because `[not] defined` operates on the `run-time` value of the variable but as it is set within a block, you would need `!result!` to access the run-time value **AND** have invoked `delayed expansion`. Further, the `/p` syntax in the set` is incorrect as this will prompt the user for input. Better to leave the `set` out altogether and use `if "%%j"=="somestring"` BUT `%%j` will never be empty - if the line is empty then `for/f` will skip the line - that iteration simply will not be executed. The comment avout the `if` syntax is valid.

Comment: @Magoo Thanks for the explanation.  I didn't look at the whole thing; just the one line with the syntax error.  If you put all of this in an answer, I'd upvote it.

Comment: Thanks for answering.